# Remember if user closed div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, caching

I want to make the cache remember if the user closed the div. How can I do this? I can close the div, but when page refreshes, it is not saved. Is there a way to do this?

Live view: http://eldeskin.com

HTML:

```
<div id="ps"><div class="close">
    <button onClick="document.getElementById('ps').style.display = 'none';">x</button></div>
<div id="heart"></div><div class="text">PSSSST!<br><br>Følger du oss på <br><a target="_blank" href="http://instagram.com/eldeskincare">Instagram</a> og <a target="_blank" href="http://facebook.com/eldeskin">Facebook</a>?</div></div>
```

CSS:

```
#ps {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 30px;
    right: 30px;
    border: 1pt solid #000;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    z-index: 99;
    background: #FFF;
    width: 300px;
}
#ps .text {
    position: relative;
    top: -30px;
}
#ps .text a {
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #c19426;
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
#ps .close {
    text-align: right !important;
}
#ps .close button {
    border: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-family: Raleway;
    background: none;
}
#heart {
    position: relative; 
    top: 94px;
    left: 135px;
    border-bottom: 1pt solid #000;
    border-right: 1pt solid #000;
    background: #FFF;
    color: #FFF;
    z-index: 6;
    width: 30px !important;
    height: 30px !important;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

Comment: Please do not link to your web site. Here's why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: There's no such thing as remember with cache, it's either cookies, local storage or serverside to keep state.

Answer (score 5):

Your best options are either storing whether or not the div has been closed in a cookie or localstorage.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the changes are gone after a refresh is normal.
you should consider using somekind of method to 'keep' those settings,
such as cookies or localstorage.
google it up, and read this article:

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/11/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/

Answer (score 0):

here is an example:

```
$('.selector').click(function() {
    localStorage.setItem('box', 'closed');
});

$(function() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('box') === 'closed') {
        $('.boxSelector').hide();
    } else {
        $('.boxSelector').show();
    }
});
```